# "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in switching to another view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, exc-bad-access

I have MainMenuViewController with button which action is

```
- (IBAction) goToFirstView {
    FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:fvc.view];
    [fvc release];
}
```

FirstViewController have UIButton with action

```
- (IBAction) rightArrow {
    SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:svc.view];
    [svc release];
}
```

But when I press "rightArrow" button app crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". Can't found my problem. Help me please.

Comment: No, I found problem, it's stupid mistake:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[svc release];
```

The problem is here. When releasing the view controller, the view's events will target a freed object, and make your program crash (probably in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear if it's instant but it doesn't matter). Note that a view does not (normally, AFAIK) retain it's view controller, if that might have been your assumption...

Answer (score 1):

When you say `[self.view addSubview:svc.view]` you're adding SecondViewController's view to FirstViewController's view. Similar with MainViewController and FirstViewController. What you'll end up with is a view hierarchy that looks like this:

- main view

  - first view

    - second view

I doubt that's really what you want. Instead, use a navigation controller with your MainViewController as the nav controller's root controller, and then use -pushViewController:animated: to push the controllers (not the views!) onto the navigation stack.

Comment: Yup, good comment. Navigation controller would have been a better approach

Comment: Yes, of course, UINavigationController is better, but UINavCon don't need me